# Border disappear when access web by Iphone or Ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, border, viewdiddisappear

I'm newbie. I have created a table ( maybe a box ) with one row and one column.

I want to see this table when I access it in PC or Laptop. But when I access it by Ipad or Iphone, I don't want to display this border.

Please tell me how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You question unclear please explain clearly what exectly you want, Are you work for desktop app or mobile app ?

Comment: Clarifying question.